# Origin on asset in asset library is diffrent from the original

Tags: origin, asset-browser, asset

I'm using the asset library browser for the first time, and I bought a people collection for it. I'm trying to add a group of people to the library so I can easily drag it into a scene. Here's the group:
[image]

All the people are parented to an empty object with the origin set to it. I moved this group to a collection and marked it as an asset. However, when I drag it out of the library again, the null object is moved all the way to the side, and it dosent move or rotate the way I like.
[image]
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All the people are parented to an empty object with the origin set to it.

Collection instancing origins are set as vector properties that hold a coordinate in scene space, not pointers to objects. If you move the objects the collection center doesn't move with it, needs to be updated manually.

[image]

Consequentially, the origin point of an instance is set as the *Collection Offset* property, which is a property of a specific collection. If you moved your group of people into a new collection then you need to set the *Collection Offset* for the new collection as well.

In the *Properties Window* check the *Collection* tab for properties of the currently active collection, or the *Object > Collections* tab to set the originins of all the collections an object may be in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it, but I'm still not sure if I fully understand. Maybe you could clarify? *Why* does the origin not move if the collection is re-instanced? And what exactly is the last step doing? Is it setting the origin to be relative rather than absolute?

Comment: Collection origin is always absolute in scene coordinates. Moving objects around has no influence on scene origin coordinates. If you moved your objects into a new collection the new collection has the default origin at [0,0,0], regardless of where your empty object is.